# Cannot receive event with custom DelegateProxy and Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, rx-swift

I try to migrate delegate of DifficultyViewDelegate to observable. This is my DifficultyViewDelegate :

```
@objc protocol DifficultyViewDelegate: class {
  func levelDidIncrease()
  func levelDidDecrease()
}
```

And my DifficultyView :

```
  weak var delegate: DifficultyViewDelegate?

  @IBAction func decreaseLevel(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.levelDidDecrease()
  }

  @IBAction func increaseLevel(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.levelDidIncrease()
  }
```

And this is my RxDifficultyViewDelegateProxy

```
class RxDifficultyViewDelegateProxy: DelegateProxy, DelegateProxyType {
  static func currentDelegateFor(_ object: AnyObject) -> AnyObject? {
    let difficultyView: DifficultyView = object as! DifficultyView
    return difficultyView.delegate
  }

  static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: AnyObject?, toObject object: AnyObject) {
    let difficultyView: DifficultyView = object as! DifficultyView
    difficultyView.delegate = delegate as? DifficultyViewDelegate
  }
}
```

I also added an extension on my DifficultyView :

```
extension DifficultyView {
  public var rx_delegate: RxDifficultyViewDelegateProxy {
    return  RxDifficultyViewDelegateProxy.proxyForObject(RxDifficultyViewDelegateProxy.self)
  }

  public var rx_levelDidIncrease: Observable<Void> {
    return rx_delegate.methodInvoked(#selector(DifficultyViewDelegate.levelDidIncrease)).map { _ in return }
  }
}
```

But it seems that when I do :

```
difficultyView.rx_levelDidIncrease.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: {
  print("did increase")
}).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

It's never called. Someone has any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `PublishSubject`:

DifficultyView:

```
class DifficultyView: UIView {
    var levelDidIncrease = PublishSubject<Void>()
    var levelDidDecrease = PublishSubject<Void>()

    @IBAction func decreaseLevel(_ sender: Any) {
        levelDidDecrease.onNext()
    }

    @IBAction func increaseLevel(_ sender: Any) {
        levelDidIncrease.onNext()
   }
}
```

And then:

```
var difficultyView = DifficultyView()

difficultyView.levelDidDecrease.asObservable()
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print("did decrease")
    })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)


difficultyView.decreaseLevel(theSender) // <- THIS line performs the side effect
```

Comment: `decreaseLevel(:)` function will be called when the IBOutlet associated is clicked.

Comment: Cool, thanks you for the pointers. But why create DifficultyViewType and not just use the PublishSubject properties ?

Comment: You don't need to create `DifficultyViewType` if you don't want to adopt that behaviour in other subviews

Comment: I've updated the answer removing the `DifficultyViewType` protocol.

Comment: I like the idea, thanks you. In the project you're working on, is it your replacement for delegate and protocol boilerplate code ?

Comment: Yes. With my own code I prefer to use it. I would use the proxy solution to encapsulate the system delegate implementations into Rx nicely.