# How to replace protocol with DelegateProxy from RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm starting to realize the benefits of using `RxSwift` and making an attempt to incorporate it into my code, but I'm not sure I'm understanding the usage of `DelegateProxy`.

Currently in my code I have the following:

```
struct SampleModel: Decodable
{
    var first_name: String
    var last_name: String

    init(first_name: String, last_name: String)
    {
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
    }
}

class ViewModel
{
    var model: SampleModel

    public var fullName: String {
        return model.first_name + model.last_name
    }

    init(model: SampleModel)
    {
        self.model = model
    }
}
```

I am using a protocol and delegate like so:

```
protocol NetworkDelegate
{
    func dataReceived(data: [Decodable]?, error: Error?)
}

class Network: NSObject
{
    var databaseLink = String()

    var networkDelegate: NetworkDelegate!

    init(databaseLink: String)
    {
        super.init()

        self.databaseLink = databaseLink
    }

    func getDatabaseData<T: Decodable>(model: T.Type)
    {
        guard let url = URL(string: databaseURL) else {
            return
        }

        request(url).responseJSON { (json) in
            switch json.result
            {
                case .success:
                    guard let data = json.data else {
                        return
                    }

                    do
                    {
                        let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self,
                                                              from: data)

                        self.networkDelegate.dataReceived(data: models,
                                                          error: nil)
                    }
                    catch let jsonErr
                    {
                        print(jsonErr)
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    self.networkDelegate.dataReceived(data: nil,
                                                      error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: NetworkDelegate
{
    func dataReceived(data: [Decodable]?, error: Error?)
    {
        guard let models = data else {
            return
        }

        for model in models
        {
            guard let myModel = model as? SampleModel else {
                return
            }

            viewModels.append( ViewModel(model: myModel) )
        }
    }
}

var viewModels = [ViewModel]()
weak var networkDelegate: NetworkDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let network = Network(databaseLink: "some url")
    network.networkDelegate = self
    network.getDatabaseData(model: SampleModel.self)
}
```

On researching this topic `RxSwift`, I've found the following:

1. [Is this the best way to convert Swift protocol to RxDelegateProxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316075/is-this-the-best-way-to-convert-swift-protocol-to-rxdelegateproxy)
2. [Cannot receive event with custom DelegateProxy and Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783083/cannot-receive-event-with-custom-delegateproxy-and-protocol)

Using it as reference I created some skeleton code:

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

protocol NetworkDelegate: class
{
    func dataReceived(data: [Decodable]?, error: Error?)
}

class NetworkDeleteProxy: DelegateProxy<ViewController, NetworkDelegate>, DelegateProxyType
{
    public static func registerKnownImplementations()
    {
        <#code#>
    }

    public static func currentDelegate(for object: ViewController) -> NetworkDelegate?
    {
        return object.networkDelegate
    }

    public static func setCurrentDelegate(_ delegate: NetworkDelegate?, to object: ViewController)
    {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```

However, I'm a bit confused afterwards on how to implement the rest of the functionality and use like the original way:

```
let network = Network(databaseLink: "some url")
network.networkDelegate = self
network.getDatabaseData(model: SampleModel.self)
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Delegate proxy relies on objc message dispatching for interception github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1442#issuecomment-335475647

Answer (score 2):

`DelegateProxy` should rather be used when integrating with Cocoa APIs that rely on `delegates`.

If you are going to go the Rx way, think of everything as a stream of events.

Let's see how we could convert your code to an observable:

```
func getDatabaseData<T: Decodable>() -> Observable<[T]>
{
    guard let url = URL(string: databaseURL) else {
        return .error(NetworkServiceErrors.missingDatabaseURL)
    }

    return Observable.create { observer in
        self.request(url).responseJSON { (json) in
            switch json.result {
            case .success:
                guard let data = json.data else {
                    return observer.onError(NetworkServiceErrors.noData)
                }

                do
                {
                    let models = try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self,
                                                          from: data)

                    observer.onNext(models)
                }
                catch let jsonErr
                {
                    observer.onError(NetworkServiceErrors.parsingError(jsonErr))
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                observer.onError(NetworkServiceErrors.someError(error))
            }
            observer.onCompleted()

            return Disposables.create { /* usually some code to cancel the request */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's now build a ViewModel using your network layer:

```
class MyListViewModel {
    // inputs
    let loadData: AnyObserver<Void>

    // outputs
    let myModels: Driver<[SampleModel]>

    private let network = Network(databaseLink: "some url")

    init() {
        let loadData = PublishRelay<Void>()
        self.loadData = loadData.asObserver()

        self.myModels = loadData.flatMapLatest { _ -> Driver<[SampleModel]>
            return network.getDatabaseData().asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
        }
    }
}
```

Your ViewController:

```
let viewModel = MyListViewModel()
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bindViewModel()
}

func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    // trigger loading of your data
    viewModel.loadData.onNext(())
}

func bindViewModel() {
    // some button that reloads data
    button.rx.tap.subscribe(viewModel.loadData).disposed(by: disposeBag)

    // will log all events but you should actually use it to drive the content of a tableview for example
    viewModel.myModels.debug().drive().disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

This is just a basic example and I haven't tested the code but it should give you an idea of what you can do.

You can look at `Moya` (a network lib) and `RxMoya` to see a some more advanced implementation or for inspiration.